# What is this type of variable assignment in Python?

Tags: python

I have seen this syntax multiple times in Python, but never known what it truly meant

Here is an example:

```
foo, bar = baz
```

Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/python/example/14981/destructuring-assignment , https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/

Comment: If someone finds a more suitable dupe target, please either edit the dupe list or let me know so I can do it. This has surely been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image is worth more than a thousand words

[image: An image is worth more than a thousand words]

Comment: No an image is not worth more than a thousand words to the users of StackOverflow that are blind and need to use a screen reader. There is no reason you couldn't type that yourself and format it to look the same

Comment: the apologies of the case

Comment: What does that even mean?

Answer (score 4):

It is unpacking multiple items in an iterable. For instance

```
foo, bar = ['thing1', 'thing2']
print(foo)
print(bar)
```

Will output

```
thing1
thing2
```

So if we say instead:

```
packed_items = ['thing1', 'thing2']
foo, bar = packed_items
print(foo)
print(bar)
```

We will get the same result.

Another important syntax to know is the `*` operator.

It can be used to grab arbitrary amounts of items while unpacking and put them in a list.

For instance:

```
packed_items = ['thing1', 'thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4', 'thing5']
foo, *middle, bar = packed_items
print(foo, middle, bar)
```

yields `thing1 ['thing2', 'thing3', 'thing4'] thing5`

Whereas

```
foo, middle, *bar = packed_items
print(foo, middle, bar)
```

Will yield `thing1 thing2 ['thing3', 'thing4', 'thing5']`

Finally, note the `*` operator can return a blank list

```
packed_items = ['thing1', 'thing2']
foo, middle, *bar = packed_items
print(foo, middle, bar)
```

Yields `thing1 thing2 []` instead of giving you an error for not having enough arguments to unpack.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to split up an iterable variable into multiple variables.  So if baz = [1, 2], foo = 1 and bar = 2.  Referred to as 'destructuring'.